# Calculating the nth digit of pi using the Bailey–Borwein–Plouffe (BBP) formula

Tags: algorithm, digits, pi

How do I calculate the *n*th binary (or hexadecimal) digit of pi using the Bailey–Borwein–Plouffe formula? I have been thoroughly searching the Internet and this site for an answer, but I've still yet to find an actual implementation for the algorithm.

The [Bailey–Borwein–Plouffe](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bailey%E2%80%93Borwein%E2%80%93Plouffe_formula) page on Wikipedia tells me that "The method calculates the *n*th digit without calculating the first `n − 1` digits, and can use small, efficient data types". The problem is, the page only explains the formula in this form:

```
Pi = SUM k=0 to infinity ...
```

But I have no clue how to use this information to actually find the *n*th digit of pi. (You know, I don't want to find the value of Pi itself, nor do I want to count a sum to infinity...) I just need to see an example in any programming language or pseudo-code on how to do this in practice.

```
int nthDigitOfPi(long n) {
    // calculate and return the n-th binary digit of pi
    // ...
}
```

Thanks in advance. Your help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: possibly related http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7265697/bailey-borwein-plouffe-formula-implementation-in-c

Comment: @גלעדברקן Thanks, but it seems that they are calculating pi to the nth digit, not arbitrary digits of pi. I could not find anything I could use to calculate the nth binary (or hexadecimal) digit of pi.

Comment: http://latkin.org/blog/2012/11/03/the-bailey-borwein-plouffe-algorithm-in-c-and-f/ and http://www.experimentalmath.info/bbp-codes/piqpr8.c

Answer (score 1):

Hey this website has a solution in python,
*[archive.org link](https://web.archive.org/web/20150627225748/http://en.literateprograms.org/Pi_with_the_BBP_formula_%28Python%29)*

I am currently trying it in php which I will post if it works ever. To clarify, did you also want the BBP solution to calculate pi?

Comment: @ChuckFulminata Archive.org to the rescue!

Comment: Note for future answerers: Chuck Fulminata's comment is _exactly_ the reason that link-only answers are discouraged on Stack Exchange sites.